# ClassNotFoundException when deploying more than 1 app to tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, classnotfoundexception

I have an application which by it's own is deployed well and works fine, however - when I deploy another one of the same application (under a different context, directory, etc) suddenly both apps are unable to load and I recieve the following exception:

```
2013-02-07 16:10:06,314 ERROR ContextLoader:307 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRequestDao' defined in class path resource [persistence.hibernate.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/hibernate/criterion/Projection
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/criterion/Projection
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1985)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:67)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.criterion.Projection
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        ... 33 more
```

I've tried practically everything and anything, but can't understand what's causing this, the jars are in the libs, and I repeat: the apps are working each when deployed individually.

Comment: How are you deploying?  What server?

Comment: What Server ? and can you post the web.xml too